# Different Size of images in drawable folder in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-drawable

In my android app development I have images with sizes 482x283 , 36x36, 48x48, 288x177 and 480x760 in "drawable-hdpi" folder what must be the sizes of these images for "drawable-mdpi", "drawable-xhdpi" , "drawable-xxhdpi" and "drawable-xxxhdpi" folders

Comment: go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hdpi = 1.5 * mdpi
xhdpi = 2 * mdpi
xxhdpi = 3 * mdpi
xxxhdpi = 4 * mdpi
```

Check Documentation for [supporting different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: SO Mdpi: 321x189
hdpi:482x28
XHDpi: 642x 378
Xxhdpi: 963x 567
Xxxhdpi: 1284x 756    Is it correct ??

Comment: mdpi: 321x189 hdpi:482x28 XHDpi: 642x 378 Xxhdpi: 963x 567 Xxxhdpi: 1284x 756 Is it ok?

Comment: only 428x284. But yeah it's correct. But maybe it's better to use sizes that always will be a whole number, like 322 inserted of 321 and. 321 * 1.5 = 481.5. It's not a problem. Just think it's better